Airflow 2.7.2 Trigger badld-written code block Triggerer's async thread
I am running Airflow version 2.7.2, and I constantly see the issue in my trigger log.
Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.50 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines.

My trigger run function is this one, it is the implementation of the BaseTrigger
async def run(self):
    while not await self.check_if_job_finished():
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
    # Send our single event and then we're done
    self.finished = True
    yield TriggerEvent(self.job_id)

This is the check if job finish function, and I use it to send Http request.
async def check_if_job_finished(self) -> bool:
    self.log.info("Check if job finished.")
    endpoint = 'abc.com'
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
    response_json = await async_http_util.async_get(url=endpoint + "/api/runtime/" + self.job_id,
                                               headers=headers, verify_ssl=False)
    if response_json['code'] == '0000':
        status = response_json['result']['status']
        if status == 'SUCCESS' or status == 'FAILED':
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        raise AirflowException("job status failed, response is: {}".format(response_json))

For sending http request, I use aiohttp.
import asyncio
import logging
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from airflow import AirflowException

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

async def async_get(url, retry_times=10, retry_wait_seconds=10, **kwargs):
    """
    Send an asynchronous HTTP GET request with retry logic.
    :param url: Request URL
    :param retry_times: Maximum number of retry attempts
    :param retry_wait_seconds: Retry interval (seconds)
    :param kwargs: Additional parameters
    :return: Response.json()
    """
    for i in range(retry_times):
        try:
            async with ClientSession() as session:
                async with session.get(url, **kwargs) as response:
                    if response.status == 200:
                        log.info(f"Request successful with {response.status}, text: {await response.text()}")
                        return await response.json()
                    else:
                        raise Exception(f"Http code is {response.status}, text: {response.text()} need to retry.")
        except Exception as e:
            log.error(f"Request failed with {e}, retrying in {retry_wait_seconds} seconds...")
            if i < retry_times - 1:
                await asyncio.sleep(retry_wait_seconds)
            else:
                raise AirflowException(f"All retries failed. {e}")

I have tried to increase the resources in my pod, but it doesn't help.
